# Roslyn replacing SyntaxNodes in depth

Tags: c#, roslyn

As example I want to add XML comments to classes, constructors and methods in a cs-file. I try different things out and everything works when I stay in the same SyntaxNode depth. But the following minimal example declares my issue.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tools.Tester
{
    class Stackoverflow
    {
        public static void Question()
        {
            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(
            @"
            public class Class
            {
                public void Method(){}
            }
            "
            );

            //REPLACE CLASS
            SyntaxNode Class = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();
            SyntaxNode ClassNew = Class.WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ParseLeadingTrivia("///<summery>XML</summery>").Add(SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine("\n")));

            /*CLASS SHOULD NOW:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public class Class
            {
                public void Method(){}
            }
            */

            //REPLACE METHOD
            SyntaxNode Method = Class.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();
            SyntaxNode MethodNew = Method.WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ParseLeadingTrivia("///<summery>XML</summery>").Add(SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine("\n")));

            /*METHOD SHOULD NOW:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public void Method(){}                
            */

            ClassNew = ClassNew.ReplaceNode(Method, MethodNew);
            /*CLASS SHOULD NOW:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public class Class
            {
                ///<summery>XML</summery>
                public void Method(){}
            }
            */

            //UPDATE TREE
            SyntaxTree treeNew = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(tree.GetRoot().ReplaceNode(Class, ClassNew).GetText());
            string code = treeNew.GetText().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(code);

            /*RESULT:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public class Class
            {                
                public void Method(){}
            }
            */
        }
    }
}
```

What is the usual way to solve this use case? Who could I update the class SyntaxNode and the method SyntaxNode?

Thanks for any response!

**Solution:**

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tools.Tester
{
    class Stackoverflow
    {
        public static void Question()
        {
            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(
            @"
            public class Class
            {
                public void Method(){}
            }
            "
            );

            //REPLACE CLASS
            SyntaxNode Class = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();
            SyntaxNode ClassNew = Class.WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ParseLeadingTrivia("///<summery>XML</summery>").Add(SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine("\n")));

            /*CLASS SHOULD NOW:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public class Class
            {
                public void Method(){}
            }
            */

            //REPLACE METHOD CHANGE TO CLASS NEW HERE
            SyntaxNode Method = ClassNew.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();
            SyntaxNode MethodNew = Method.WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ParseLeadingTrivia("///<summery>XML</summery>").Add(SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine("\n")));

            /*METHOD SHOULD NOW:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public void Method(){}                
            */

            ClassNew = ClassNew.ReplaceNode(Method, MethodNew);
            /*CLASS SHOULD NOW:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public class Class
            {
                ///<summery>XML</summery>
                public void Method(){}
            }
            */

            //UPDATE TREE
            SyntaxTree treeNew = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(tree.GetRoot().ReplaceNode(Class, ClassNew).GetText());
            string code = treeNew.GetText().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(code);

            /*RESULT:
            ///<summery>XML</summery>
            public class Class
            {                
                public void Method(){}
            }
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take method syntax from the new class syntax, not from the old, otherwise your replacition doesn't affect anything, because new class syntax doesn't contain the method syntax from the old class syntax to replace it.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria small mistake, big outcome, like always. Thanks for help! :-)